# Add scrollbars to a background image

Tags: html, css

How can I add scrollbars to this image background?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>VBS</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-image: url(https://imgur.com/CahbpxJ.jpg);
            min-height: 100%;
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The reason I put the image in the background is that I need to put buttons and other elements on top of it. Is there another way to achieve that?

Comment: No, it's a background-image.

Comment: Why one would ever wants to have a scrollbar for the background? Background is jut a background. If it is an important content, then it shouldn't be in the background. Bring it to the front and make it a standard `img` element or a background for a standard element. And while at it, consider deleting this question so you can restore your lost rep back.

Comment: May i know the necessity of adding scroll bars to background img?

Comment: If you add it as an <img> then you cant put buttons etc on top of that image. If you add it as a background, then you can add elements on top of the image

Comment: Yes, you can add buttons etc. on top. but if it is a background-image it should also be implemented as a background image. but a background image can't be so important that it needs scrollbars.

Comment: You can put almost whatever you want on almost whatever you want. HTML is a very powerful layout language and there are many options to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your original question is:

Why one would ever wants to have a scrollbar for the background? Background is just a background. If it is an important content, then it shouldn't be in the background. Bring it to the front and make it a standard `img` element or a background for a standard element.

If we convert your comment:

> If you add it as an `<img>` then you cant put buttons etc on top of that image. If you add it as a background, then you can add elements on top of the image

to a question:

> How to put buttons and other elements on top of an image?

then the answer would be: There are many ways to do it. One way can be by putting the image inside a `div` box that is `position: relative` and then add the button (or any element you want) to the box and make it `position: absolute`. And then you can add scrolls to the `div` box. Here is a demo:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.container button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://imgur.com/CahbpxJ.jpg" />
  <button type="button">Click Me</button>
</div>
```